# Domain wide delegation with the go gmail API client

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I have a service account set up, with domain wide delegation enabled. Using the account's json credentials file, I have successfully made calls to the Gmail API with [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) (so I know the service account and its access rights are fine).

My question is basically how to specify the delegated account with the [gmail client library](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1). Here's what I have so far:

```
g, e := gmail.NewService(
    context.Background(),
    option.WithScopes(gmail.MailGoogleComScope),
    option.WithCredentialsFile("/path/to/serviceAccount.json"),

    // Something missing to pass the account we are delegating;
    // e.g., someone@mycompany.com
)
```

The service is created, but if I try to use it, I get

```
googleapi: Error 400: Precondition check failed., failedPrecondition
```

which is the expected error when `oauth2l` is not passed the `--email` flag. Any ideas?